# Variables involving complex numbers in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran, fortran77

Is there a program developed in Fortran to allow interpolation (or extrapolation calculus) of variables involving complex numbers (z = x + i y) ...

In fact, I have a set of complex numbers, each value (real and imaginary) corresponding to a given integer harmonic order for example: harmonic order 1, value (a + i b), ..., harmonic order 10, value (c + i d) and so on, for 25 integers harmonic orders ​​and corresponding complexes values...

Is there a Fortran program that allow me to interpolate or extrapolate the values ​​for any orders of integer harmonics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is currently no library for interpolation between two complex numbers. You are most likely going to have to develop your library for interpolation and extrapolation.

Linear interpolation and extrapolation is straight forward to implement. For higher order relations you can consider using [INTERP](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/interp/interp.html) and also [QUADPACK](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f_src/quadpack/quadpack.html) for calculus.